# Change image by click of list view item in Visual Studio 2012 c# and xaml

Tags: c#, listview, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I am trying to build a program which includes a listview, i have the listview in place but what i want to happen, but isn't, is that **when i click on a specific list view item i want the image to change.** I am using Visual Studio 2012 and designing for Windows Store
NOT the Windows Phone

For example, i have Albert Einstein as the first listview element, when the user clicks on this list view item i would like a picture of Albert Einstein to appear in the image element, vice versa when the user clicks second element in listview an image of Galileo should appear, i have all images pre-loaded

```
private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ScientistListView.SelectedIndex==0)
    {
        ImageForScience.Source = new ImageSource(new Uri("Benjamin_Franklin.png", UriKind.Absolute));
        textBelowHistory.Text = @"Einstein was born in 1879 in Germany (Ulm, Wuttemberg) and died on April 18 1955 
        He developed the special and general theories of relativity

        While working in a patent office Einstein had time to work on his theories of relativity
        In 1915 Einstein completed his general theory of relativity
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be the way to display a image, assuming that it is stored in one of your folders,
In this examples I'm retrieving it from the assets folder.

```
 string path = "/Assets/none.jpg";
                Uri uriPath = new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative);
                BitmapImage image1 = new BitmapImage(uriPath);
                Picturebox1.Source = image1;
```

Comment: When i enter bitmap the only options that appear are 'bitConverter' and 'BitmapCache' i am not sure why

Comment: using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;   add this namespace... and try again , if you haven't got it yet then search this way: Right click "References" in the Solution Explorer, select Add Reference. in the popup click the *Brows*e tab. Look for the specific file you want to reference. Now make sure you have the declaration at the top of your class.

Comment: I have done everything you have told me and have searched in the folder after pressing browse but cannot find the namespace you specified in your last comment.

Comment: did you try this System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage

Comment: No luck, excuse my ignorance but what folder am i supposed to be looking in for these namespaces? i am by default brought to the System32 folder

Comment: Which version of viusal studio are you using and whic platform are you targeting(wp8 or wp7)? If you are using vs2012 then the references comes automaticaly and you should be able to include this: using System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage if you are using vs2010 then you can only target wp7

Comment: I have found it mate, i went into references folder and found PresentationCore.dll file, but i am doing the project c# for windows store and haven't got the picturebox element, and when type in your code i dont enter 'Picturebox1.source = image1' i type in 'imageScience.source = ImageOfScience' but it says i cannot convert

Comment: It says i cannot convert 'System.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage' to windows.ui.xaml.media.imageSource'

Comment: By the way i am using visual studio 2012 and i am targeting wp8

Comment: using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging; do you have this namespace then?

Comment: look, in your code, ImageForScience.Source = new ImageSource(new Uri("Benjamin_Franklin.png", UriKind.Absolute)); just add the folder that you are getting the image from not just the image name, refference my asnwer to see how it is done properly...

Comment: I have this at the moment 

string path = "/Assets/Benjamin_Franklin.png";
                Uri uriPath = new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative);
                BitmapImage image1 = new BitmapImage(uriPath);

                ImageForScience.Source = new ImageSource(new Uri("Assets/Benjamin_Franklin.png", UriKind.Absolute));

Comment: Although the  ImageForScience.Source = new ImageSource(new Uri("Assets/Benjamin_Franklin.png", UriKind.Absolute)); is underlined in red in my code

Comment: Now I'm completely lost I must say. Never mind. If you are using ImageSource class then you are using the .Media name-space! and you are saying that you can not find it this is what I do not understand.Once again try to find the dll although as I said it comes inside the default windows phone 8 application.Second thing, provide the folder/image_name path and you should definitely have your image displayed. At last delete this namespace, windows.ui.xaml.media.imageSource' and then go with the folder/image_name and see if you get your image if not then try to find the dll

Comment: Ok thanks for your help it has given me an insight in what I need to do I might leave it for now

Comment: I don't know what else to say. please if you solve your problem and I'm sure you will, then post your solution and mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 BitmapImage ImageName= new BitmapImage(new Uri( this.BaseUri,"Assets/PicturName.png"));

    ImageForScience.Source = ImageName;
```

This will create a new bitmapImage as well as creating a new Uri and then sets that 'string'
 to the baseUri which will represented as the xaml constructed object when at load time

I am setting the bitmap image to the source of my 'image' element within my program
I can do this multiple times so new and different URI can be loaded at run time.

Comment: Please explain why this works. This may not be obvious to the OP.